# Splitting a string?

Tags: python, string, list, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string into a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216489/splitting-a-string-into-a-list-in-python)

I'd like to take user input and break it apart character by character. Basically I have this

```
string = raw_input("String: ")
print string
```

Now I want to split each of these letters and put them into a list. So lets say I input hello, I get a list like `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert this string to a list.  It is already an iterable sequence of individual characters so the conversion is automatic.

```
string = raw_input("String: ")
print(list(string))
```

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't need to, since strings are iterable regardless. But:

```
print list('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [c for c in string]
print s
```